# Is it sufficient to find an injective function and a surjective function to show cardinality of two sets is equal?

Tags: analysis, cardinals

Here's the question I am solving:

Let,

$P = [0, 1),QR = [0, 1) × [0, 1) = \{(x, y) ∈ \Bbb R^2: 0 ≤ x, y < 1\}$

Show that,

$card(P) = card(QR)$

This is what I have so far:

To show the sets P and QR are equal in cardinality, I aim to show that there is an injective function from $f: P→QR$ and a surjective function $g: QR→P$. This would mean there is a bijection and therefore $card(P) = card(QR)$

An injective function $y = (1-x)$ satisfies the given conditions and since there is an injective function $f: P→QR$ , it implies that $card(P)\le card(QR)$

I'm stuck trying to finding an example of a surjective function $g: QR→P$ that can show $card(P)\ge card(QR)$. Is the inverse function $x=(1-y)$ sufficient to show surjectivity?

I'm not certain of my answer, if it is correct and I'm just overthinking a trivial answer or if I'm trying to solve it incorrectly altogether.

Comment: An injective function $A\to B$ and a surjective function $A\to B$: yes. An injective function $A\to B$ and a surjective function $B\to A$ (which is what you're trying to do): no. For instance, if $A=\{1\}$ and $B=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, there is an injective function $A\to B$ and there is a surjective function $B\to A$, but there is no bijection between $A$ and $B$.

Comment: By the way your function $y=1-x$ is not even a function from $P$ to $QR$ because the elements of $QR$ are not real numbers, they are ordered pairs of real numbers, If you want an injection $f:P\to QR$ how about $f(x)=(x,0)$?

Comment: As a side note,  given any injection $f:A\to B$ we immediately get a (partial or fulll) inverse function $f^{-1}$  defined on a subset of $B$ that is surjective, one can then extend it to a full surjective function in any way you want (Like pick a constant value in $A$ for all the points not in the range of $f$, doesn't even take AC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, suppose we have sets $A, B$, with a surjective function $g : A \to B$ and an injective function $f : A \to B$.

The axiom of choice states (in one of several equivalent forms) that whenever $g : A \to B$ is a surjective function, there is a function $h : B \to A$ such that $g \circ h = 1_B$ - that is, such that for all $b \in B$, $g(h(b)) = b$.

This means that $h : B \to A$ is an injective function.

Since we have injective functions $f : A \to B$ and $h : B \to A$, we apply the Schroeder-Bernstein Theorem to conclude $|A| = |B|$.

*However*, this is not the tactic OP is using. OP is constructing an injective function $A \to B$ and a surjective function $B \to A$ [where $A = P$ and $B = QR$ in OP's case]. This is *not* enough to show that $|A| = |B|$.

Consider, for example, $A$ a 1-element set and $B$ a 2-element set. It's easy to see that both of the two functions $A \to B$ are injective, and also that the single function $B \to A$ is surjective. But $|A| \neq |B|$.